# Extracting numbers from a string into an ArrayList

Tags: java, homework

This first stores a string as input, loops through it to extract all of the numbers into an `ArrayList`, then prints all of these numbers along with their sum and product.

How would I decompose this Java program into multiple methods?

```
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Creates scanner for storing input string
        Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        System.out.println("Enter a string of numbers to compute their sum and product:");
        System.out.println("(Enter '.' to terminate program)");
        input = numScanner.nextLine();

        // Terminates the program if there is no input
        if (input.length() == 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid input: Not enough characters");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // Terminates the program if the first character is '.'
        if (input.charAt(0) == '.'){
            System.out.println("Thank you for using numberScanner!");
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        // Defines all of the variables used in the loops
        int index = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int product = 1; 
        Integer start = null;
        int end = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        // Loop that extracts all numbers from the string and computes their sum and product
        while (index < input.length()){
            if (input.charAt(index) >= 'A' && input.charAt(index) <= 'Z' && start == null){
                index++;
            }else if (input.charAt(index) >= '1' && input.charAt(index) <= '9' && start == null){
                start = index;
                index++;
            }else if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(index))){
                index++;
            }else{
                end = index;
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end)));
                sum += Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end));
                product *= Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start,end));
                index++;
                start = null;
            }   
        }

        // For the last number, the end is greater than the length of the string
        // This prints the last number without using the end
        if (index == input.length()){
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start)));
            sum += Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start));
            product *= Integer.parseInt(input.substring(start));
            index++;
        }

        // Prints the Numbers, Sum and Product beside each other
        System.out.print("Numbers: ");
        for (Object a : numbers) {
            System.out.print(a.toString() + " ");
            }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + " Product: " + product);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems on-topic to me, as the OP is asking for help refactoring. That seems right up our alley.

Answer (score 1):

Start by separating your code into input handling, computation, and output.  Each of those could have its own method(s).

For the input, you're working too hard.  The `java.util.Scanner` has methods to give you `int`s.

Think about what the inputs and outputs of each function should be.  For example, your input handling function should take an `InputStream` and return a `List` of `Integer`s or an array of `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you a functional solution, but here's roughly what it should look like.

```
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = gatherInput();
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers =  extractIntegers(input);

        int sum = sumInts(numbers);
        int  product = multiplyInts(numbers);

        reportResults(numbers, sum, product);
}
```

The key thing you need to keep in mind is that a method should do just one thing.  I could have combined sumInts and multiplyInts, but they are mostly independent concepts -- so, keep them separate unless there's a performance problem or you need something a bit more abstract (ie you have a list of operations you want to apply to the elements of the list).  I would suggest that you consider variations on the above revolving around "reportResults"...there are two variations that should be fairly obvious.

Comment: you should honour java code conventions and start method names with lower case letters though.

Answer (score 1):

What @jmoreno has said is pretty much spot on but seeing as this is a java problem remember that the convention is to use lower case letters for method names.

The important things to remember are that each method should be simple, readable, encapsulate a unit of work and be easily testable. Again, following what @jmoreno has said and considering the gatherInput method, you can take the first five lines of code and create a new method that returns your string input. If you are using Eclipse this is very easy, highlight the code and click Alt+Shift+M which will open the 'Extract Method' refactor dialog box.

The loop is the only real place where you have to think a little more as currently it is doing multiple jobs, but if you break out the code that extracts the numbers (extractIntegers(input)) then the rest becomes easy - you should also be able to remove the additional index == input.length() test.

Other considerations:

1. Have you thought about a for loop instead of a while loop? All of your cases increment the index by 1.
2. Do you know how the input string should be formatted, in which case you could use a regular expression to extract the numbers.
3. You have used isDigit once, why have you mixed it with the >= <= solution? What about the letters?